# How to pass String in to fs.readFileSync

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert string in to Buffer using `readFileSync`.It's return buffer with hard coded string.but not when i pas string.

----working ---

```
const buffer = fs.readFileSync('./test/JFwZCrdEojAr09ajT8EPZmo.jpg',{ encoding: 'utf8' });
```

----not working ---

```
var pathString = './test/JFwZCrdEojAr09ajT8EPZmo.jpg';
const buffer = fs.readFileSync(pathString,{ encoding: 'utf8' });
```

i'm getting bellow error

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   './test/JFwZCrdEojAr09ajT8EPZmo.jpg'

Both ways working fine in local machine.but when deploy in to server,above happening.

Comment: Check your file, probably it was moved/erased after the first run. Listed code is fine.

Comment: @Drag13 image file is not erased.it's on same directory

Comment: @YasiruAttanayake The code is exactly the same on your both examples. The truth is somewhere else :)

Comment: Are both of these examples placed in the same file and place in code? May be current directory wasn't resolved correctly in 2nd example. You can add console.log(process.cwd()) before each statement to see workingdir

Comment: @Stepan That's what i wonder.But both ways working charmly in local machine.This is happening when deploy to server.

Comment: Did you try changing the './' with your domain URL?

Comment: @Luthfi yes i have tested it with `__dirname` also

Comment: How about the permission?, does your account have the permission to read? perhaps it's because of this. Try to set the permission of your folder and files that your system want to read.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Answer (score 0):

Both should be work. check your image file still exists.